# How to correctly serialize API response in Django view

Tags: python, django

I am calling the Giphy API using another [wrapper API](https://github.com/Giphy/giphy-python-client) which returns a **list of dictionaries**. I am having hard times to serialize the data to return it to AJAX.

The data is returned as `InlineResponse200` with three [properties](https://github.com/Giphy/giphy-python-client/blob/master/docs/InlineResponse200.md).
([docu](https://github.com/Giphy/giphy-python-client/blob/master/docs/Gif.md))

The problem is that my view is not able to return the JSON properly:

```
# Traceback
[2020-06-23 14:58:54,086] log: ERROR - Internal Server Error: /get_gifs/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\Desktop\finsphere\finsphere\blog\views.py", line 234, in get_gifs
    return JsonResponse(api_response.data[0])
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\http\response.py", line 554, in __init__
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: In order to allow non-dict objects to be serialized set the safe parameter to False.
[23/Jun/2020 14:58:54] "POST /get_gifs/ HTTP/1.1" 500 17874
```

If I add `safe=False` it returns `TypeError: Object of type Gif is not JSON serializable`

I don't get this since `api_response.data[0]` is a cristal clear dictionary.

**Desired outcome:** Get the Giphy object logged in the success function of Ajax.

**AJAX**

```
(function($) {
  $('#btnSearch').on('click', function(e) {
      var query = $('#search').val();
      console.log(query);
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        async: true,
        url: '/get_gifs/',
        data: {
          'query': query,
          'csrfmiddlewaretoken': window.CSRF_TOKEN // from blog.html
        },
        success: function(response) {

        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
          // shit happens friends!
        }
    });
  });
}(jQuery));
```

(Inserted my original -free- API key for reproduction)

**Views.py**

```
def get_gifs(request):

        # create an instance of the API class
        api_instance = giphy_client.DefaultApi()

        # API Key
        api_key = 'NGSKWrBqtIq1rFU1Ka11D879Y1u4Igia'

        # Search term
        q = request.POST.get('query')
        print(q)

        # Query parameters
        limit = 2
        offset = 0
        rating = 'g'
        lang = 'en'
        fmt = 'json'

        try:
            # Search Endpoint
            api_response = api_instance.gifs_search_get(api_key, q, limit=limit, offset=offset, rating=rating, lang=lang, fmt=fmt)
            pprint(api_response)
        except ApiException as e:
            print("Exception when calling DefaultApi->gifs_search_get: %s\n" % e)

        return JsonResponse(api_response.data[0])
```

**API fetched object (pprint api_response)**

```
{'data': [{'bitly_gif_url': 'https://gph.is/g/EJWjdvN',
           'bitly_url': 'https://gph.is/g/EJWjdvN',
           'content_url': '',
           'create_datetime': None,
           'embed_url': 'https://giphy.com/embed/J0JGg6doLfmV0yZmIB',
           'featured_tags': None,
           'id': 'J0JGg6doLfmV0yZmIB',
           'images': {'downsized': {'height': '250',
                                    'size': '350582',
                                    'url': 'https://media3.giphy.com/media/J0JGg6doLfmV0yZmIB/giphy.gif?cid=ecefd82565bc1664c2b17e3e4b60d88c736d0c6b5a39d682&rid=giphy.gif',
                                    'width': '478'},
                      'downsized_large': {'height': '250',
                                          'size': '350582',
                                          'url': 'https://media3.giphy.com/media/J0JGg6doLfmV0yZmIB/giphy.gif?cid=ecefd82565bc1664c2b17e3e4b60d88c736d0c6b5a39d682&rid=giphy.gif',
                                          'width': '478'},
                      'preview_gif': {'height': '134',
                                      'size': '49623',
                                      'url': 'https://media3.giphy.com/media/J0JGg6doLfmV0yZmIB/giphy-preview.gif?cid=ecefd82565bc1664c2b17e3e4b60d88c736d0c6b5a39d682&rid=giphy-preview.gif',
                                      'width': '256'}},
           'import_datetime': '2020-06-15 10:01:39',
           'is_anonymous': None,
           'is_community': None,
           'is_featured': None,
           'is_hidden': None,
           'is_indexable': None,
           'is_realtime': None,
           'is_removed': None,
           'is_sticker': False,
           'rating': 'g',
           'slug': 'MITEF-mitefarab-asc2020-J0JGg6doLfmV0yZmIB',
           'source': 'www.mitefarab.org',
           'source_post_url': 'www.mitefarab.org',
           'source_tld': '',
           'tags': None,
           'trending_datetime': '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
           'type': 'gif',
           'update_datetime': None,
           'url': 'https://giphy.com/gifs/MITEF-mitefarab-asc2020-J0JGg6doLfmV0yZmIB',
           'user': {'avatar_url': 'https://media2.giphy.com/avatars/MITEF/8FTlysEjtXzx.jpg',
                    'banner_url': '',
                    'display_name': 'MITEF Pan Arab',
                    'profile_url': 'https://giphy.com/MITEF/',
                    'twitter': None,
                    'username': 'MITEF'},
           'username': 'MITEF'},
          {'bitly_gif_url': 'https://gph.is/g/ZdxQQpP',
           'bitly_url': 'https://gph.is/g/ZdxQQpP',
           'content_url': '',
           'create_datetime': None,
           'embed_url': 'https://giphy.com/embed/hTJF0O4vDkJsUi1h8Q',
           'featured_tags': None,
           'id': 'hTJF0O4vDkJsUi1h8Q',
           'images': {'downsized': {'height': '480',
                                    'size': '310971',
                                    'url': 'https://media3.giphy.com/media/hTJF0O4vDkJsUi1h8Q/giphy.gif?cid=ecefd82565bc1664c2b17e3e4b60d88c736d0c6b5a39d682&rid=giphy.gif',
                                    'width': '480'},                      
                      'preview': {'height': '480',
                                  'mp4': 'https://media3.giphy.com/media/hTJF0O4vDkJsUi1h8Q/giphy-preview.mp4?cid=ecefd82565bc1664c2b17e3e4b60d88c736d0c6b5a39d682&rid=giphy-preview.mp4',
                                  'mp4_size': '15536',
                                  'width': '480'},
                      'preview_gif': {'height': '480',
                                      'size': '22387',
                                      'url': 'https://media3.giphy.com/media/hTJF0O4vDkJsUi1h8Q/giphy-preview.gif?cid=ecefd82565bc1664c2b17e3e4b60d88c736d0c6b5a39d682&rid=giphy-preview.gif',
                                      'width': '480'}},
           'import_datetime': '2019-07-19 22:27:40',
           'is_anonymous': None,
           'is_community': None,
           'is_featured': None,
           'is_hidden': None,
           'is_indexable': None,
           'is_realtime': None,
           'is_removed': None,
           'is_sticker': False,
           'rating': 'g',
           'slug': 'RecargaPay-cashback-recargapay-paguetudopelocelular-hTJF0O4vDkJsUi1h8Q',
           'source': 'www.recargapay.com.br',
           'source_post_url': 'www.recargapay.com.br',
           'source_tld': '',
           'tags': None,
           'trending_datetime': '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
           'type': 'gif',
           'update_datetime': None,
           'url': 'https://giphy.com/gifs/RecargaPay-cashback-recargapay-paguetudopelocelular-hTJF0O4vDkJsUi1h8Q',
           'user': {'avatar_url': 'https://media0.giphy.com/avatars/RecargaPay/msKTiPaVkvqd.png',
                    'banner_url': 'https://media0.giphy.com/headers/RecargaPay/kg023vdaAaWA.gif',
                    'display_name': 'RecargaPay',
                    'profile_url': 'https://giphy.com/RecargaPay/',
                    'twitter': None,
                    'username': 'RecargaPay'},
           'username': 'RecargaPay'}],
 'meta': {'msg': 'OK',
          'response_id': '65bc1664c2b17e3e4b60d88c736d0c6b5a39d682',
          'status': 200},
 'pagination': {'count': 2, 'offset': 0, 'total_count': 10}}
```

Comment: are you trying to return JSON response?

Comment: @VishalSingh I tried this, yes. See the first code snippet, it raises error: TypeError: Object of type Gif is not JSON serializable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I go though your code everything is correct except `return JsonResponse(api_response.data[0])` in your views

**JsonResponse**:

The **first parameter, data, should be a dict instance.** If the **safe parameter is set to False**, it can be any JSON-serializable object. [official documentation link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects)

When you say

**1.** `safe=True`

```
return JsonResponse(api_response.data[0])

TypeError: In order to allow non-dict objects to be serialized set the safe parameter to False.
```

The error is obvious `api_response.data[0]` is not dict, see point 2 error

**2**
`safe=False`

```
return JsonResponse(api_response.data[0], safe=False)
TypeError: Object of type Gif is not JSON serializable
```

The data **api_response.data[0]** you provide to JsonResponse **is not a dict type object actually**, that's why you got error for first point.

when you say `safe=False` JsonResponse is trying to serialize object but that object is not json serializable, you can trace-back error

```
File "....\Python\Python38\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type Gif is not JSON serializable
```

Can be followed the [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) to see which object can be Json serializable

Coming back to your error.

*I don't get this since `api_response.data[0]` is a cristal clear dictionary.*

type of `api_response` and `api_response.data[0]`

```
type(api_response)
<class 'giphy_client.models.inline_response_200.InlineResponse200'>
type(api_response.data[0])
<class 'giphy_client.models.gif.Gif'>
```

You can follow for giphy_client [documentation link](https://github.com/Giphy/giphy-python-client#documentation-for-models) for more-details

**Solution**:

```
result = api_response.data[0].to_dict()   ## NOTE to_dict function of giphy_client.models.gif.Gif

return JsonResponse(result)
```

Comment: well deserved, well deserved  my friend. Thank you so much! I will award the bounty once possible (in 3 hours  time)

Comment: I am glad to know my answer helped you, Thanks! @Jonas

Answer (score 1):

```
render(request, template_name, context=None, content_type=None, status=None, using=None)
```

> `render()` Combines a given template with a given context dictionary
> and returns an HttpResponse object with that rendered text.

You can either use Django defaults `JsonResponse` class or Django REST framework `Response` class to return JSON responses.

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
return JsonResponse(data=api_response.data)

from rest_framework.response import Response
return Response(data=api_response.data)
```

tried it on the ipython shell and it works just fine.

```
In [15]: response = Response(api_response.data[0])                                                                                                                              

In [16]: response                                                                                                                                                               
Out[16]: <Response status_code=200, "text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

`response.data` gives me the serialized response.

Comment: ah I messed up the class, true. Using JsonResponse it still says it isn't a dict object. I updated my post.

Comment: @Jonas in your case use the `Response` class provided by the Django REST framework.

Comment: I tried the approach and have a different error now. I added it to the initial post. Thanks!

Comment: @Jonas assigning the first element to the api_response.data i.e `api_response.data = data[0]` is not a good idea because as you said you're calling the Giphy API using another wrapper API and you do not know what is going on behind the curtains. Try this `return Response(data=api_response.data[0])`

Comment: raising error: TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()
 now

Comment: @Jonas try removing `@renderer_classes((JSONRenderer))`.

Comment: thanks for your efforts mate^^ this is rly a messy issue. Now I get: TypeError: Object of type Gif is not JSON serializable

Comment: would you mind to post your working solution from the ipython shell? Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216404/discussion-between-vishal-singh-and-jonas).

Answer (score 0):

Python has a built in function for converting dicts to json.

```
import json

data = api_response.data
return render(request, json.dumps(data))
```

If you use that in your return statement it should return json.